# Unclickeable PDF download page Chrome Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote the following procedure, based on Selenium and Chrome, to download a PDF file to a defined folder, after performing some actions on a web app:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory' : path_to_destination, 
             "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
         
         # Additional options I've tried but didn't work
         #,"download.prompt_for_download": False,
         # 'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1,
         # "helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": mime_types,
         # "plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types": mime_types
         }
    
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs) 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=executable_path,
    chrome_options=chrome_options
    )
```

However, as soon as I click on the link that, normally, allows to visualize the pdf, the following unclickable page is displayed:

[image]

As soon as I manually click on it, everything works fine and the file is correctly downloaded to the indicated folder ("path_to_destination");

I tried with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'open-button')]").click()

# Or 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'main-content')]").click()
```

Since the xpath is:

```
//*[@id="main-content"]/a
```

But it does not work.
How can I either avoid opening this second page or clicking on the "Apri" (= Open) button?

P.S. Using Firefox and the following options, everything works fine:

```
# Setup
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    
    mime_types = "application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,"\
        "application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml"
    
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", full_destination)
    
    # For PDFs
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mime_types)
    profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", mime_types)
    profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
```

Comment: Try `elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'open-button')]"); driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', elem)`

Comment: The resulting exception is: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id, 'open-button')]"}

Comment: You will get more help if you update your question with the URL for the page in question and the exception (showing it in a comment is not the best way to describe the problem). It may be that the presentation is being loaded by JavaScript and you need to wait for the element to appear, but you have not shown a *minimal reproducible example* so there is no way for anyone to really offer much insight. That is, you need to provide minimal but enough code that reproduces the error.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; unfortunately, it's a private page; that's why I haven't updated the url. Is there something more I can provide?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to `prefs`:

```
"download.prompt_for_download": False
```

Comment: It doesn't work, please check the trials (commented out) that I've already done